# PHP foreach update custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I use ACF Pro google maps.
The Plugin stores the map data in an array. So far so good.

Now, I like to run through the array and directly store the date in new custom fields.

This works, but I like to give the fields my own name, not the names from the ARRAY (lat & lng).

Can anyone explain how I can use my own names for the custom fields spot_lat & spot_lng?

```php
function my_copy_date_filter($post_id)
{
  $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
  if ($post_type != 'spot') {
    return;
  }
  $date = get_field('spot_location', $post_id);
  if ($date) {
    $lat_lng = [];
    foreach (array('lat', 'lng') as $i => $k) {
      if (isset($date[$k])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $k, $date[$k]);
      }
    }
  }
}
add_filter('acf/save_post', 'my_copy_date_filter', 20);
```

Thanks for any suggestion,
Denis

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 new acf fields named spot_lat  and spot_lng

Then try this code

```
function my_copy_date_filter($post_id) {
$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
if ($post_type != 'spot') {
    return;
}
$date = get_field('spot_location', $post_id);   
if( $date ) {

update_field( 'spot_lat', $date[ 'lat' ], $post_id );

update_field( 'spot_lng', $date[ 'lng' ], $post_id );

}

} 
add_filter('acf/save_post', 'my_copy_date_filter', 20);
```